# How to Managed ALL running Threads in C# console appication?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, console-application, threadpool

I having problem managed thread parallel in console application.
I am running 10 threads parallel & all thread doing some specific task.
In case if any task is over/completed then doing stop/end thread and immediate I started new thread instance. 
 I want 10 threads so anyone thread is going to stop/end then It generates new thread. 
 but every time I want 10 threads in running mode in console application & 
It should be parallel work using C# console application. 

How I can running 10 threads in C# console application?

Comment: A ThreadPool comes to mind for such a task. Also, your question makes no sense, especially towards the end. Please rephrase it.

Comment: @Alex why my question has no sense..?

Comment: If you have 10 threads, why let them quit, only to make a new one? Why not do more work with the existing thread?

Comment: @spender I having 10 different task so I running 10 separate thread. How can I do more task from existing thread?? please explain more about multiple threading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of each thread put a lock on some shared object (lock (obj) {}).
Then remove the current thread from a collection of threads you have.
If the collection.Count is less than 10 create a new one and put inside the collection.
Release the lock.

```
private List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();

private void ThreadFunction() {
  // do something
  // here before the lock
  lock (threads) {
    threads.Remove(Thread.CurrentThread);
    if (thread.Count < 10) {
      Thread t = new Thread(ThreadFunction);
      threads.Add(t);
      t.Start();
    }
  }
}
```

Be sure to catch all exception inside the thread or you code will fail when a thread exception happens. That is make sure that the lock part of the code is always called (except on a Thread abord exception but that will not matter).

But as stated I think you should use a ThreadPool for such a task...

Answer (score 0):

The book on threads in .Net is: http://www.albahari.com/threading/
This alone will probably answer any questions you have.

Depending on what you are using these threads for (I am guessing that you may be talking about running transactions in the background) you may want to use BackgroundWorker.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

BackgroundWorker lets you deal with Begin/End/Progress Events only, making debugging much less error prone.